# Passing css classes through props to a children component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styling

So, i have a css file with determined classes, lets say (class1,class2,class3,etc) and i need to make a presentational component that passes through props their properties to a child component. if the called name in the child component then the properties of the css class are available to use.

Comment: I'd recommend you include some sample code that you've tried and talk about where you're stuck.

Comment: `their properties to a child component.` -- where do these properties come from, are they hard-coded in presentational component, or are they passed to it? `if the called name in the child component then the properties of the css class are available to use` -- can you explain this further, what does "called name in child component" refer to and where do you want CSS classes applied?

Answer (score 0):

`props.children` = the component(s) nested inside that component. We can use `React.cloneElement()` in order to pass properties into the child.

```
const PresentationalComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const hardCodedClassName = '.some-class';
  return (
    <>
        {React.cloneElement(props.children, { className: hardCodedClassName })}
    </>
  )
}

// Usage

<PresentationalComponent>
  <ChildComponent />
</PresentationalComponent>
```